Python How to Create a Temporary File Object for "moviepy" VideoFileClip.audio?
I need to perform certain operations on audio from VideoFileClip.audio object. The operations require that I pass an audio file object.
I need to create a temporary file object for this purpose.
I used VideoFileClip.audio.write_audiofile function to store in a io.BytesIO object. The function didn't proceed as expected due to this:
> self.audio = io.BytesIO()
> self.video.audio.write_audiofile(self.audio)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO

I have discovered using tempfile is an option, but it does not suit my case as it'll be creating actual files and I'll be performing this operation on a large scale.
